# cmu sphinx : TranscriberDemo showing exception for non-english model configuration

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, non-english

TranscriberDemo 
(reference repo : sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/5prealpha/) is showing following exceptions while configuring model related to non-english language (sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/Russian/zero_ru_cont_8k_v3.tar.gz).

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13568, Size: 13568
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Pool.get(Pool.java:55)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Sphinx3Loader.createSenonePool(Sphinx3Loader.java:428)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Sphinx3Loader.loadModelFiles(Sphinx3Loader.java:313)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Sphinx3Loader.load(Sphinx3Loader.java:252)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.AutoCepstrum.newProperties(AutoCepstrum.java:118)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:163)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponentList(PropertySheet.java:432)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.FrontEnd.newProperties(FrontEnd.java:160)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:296)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.SimpleAcousticScorer.newProperties(SimpleAcousticScorer.java:47)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:296)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.newProperties(WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:213)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstLookaheadSearchManager.newProperties(WordPruningBreadthFirstLookaheadSearchManager.java:156)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:296)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.AbstractDecoder.newProperties(AbstractDecoder.java:81)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.newProperties(Decoder.java:36)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:296)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.newProperties(Recognizer.java:86)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:518)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:163)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.<init>(Context.java:73)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.<init>(Context.java:45)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.AbstractSpeechRecognizer.<init>(AbstractSpeechRecognizer.java:44)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.StreamSpeechRecognizer.<init>(StreamSpeechRecognizer.java:35)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.transcriber.TranscriberDemo.streamSpeechDemo(TranscriberDemo.java:66)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.demo.transcriber.TranscriberDemo.main(TranscriberDemo.java:32)
```

my model configuration is as below:

> ```
> static String acousticModelPath = "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/ru/ru";
> static String dictionaryPath    = "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/ru/ru.dic";
> static String languageModelPath = "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/ru/ru.lm";
> static String streamPath      = "E:\\ews\\sphinx4-5prealpha-src\\sphinx4-5prealpha-src\\sphinx4-data\\src\\main\\resources\\edu\\cmu\\sphinx\\models\\ru\\decoder-test.wav";
> ```

Comment: configured for ptm acoustic-model (zero_ru.cd_ptm_4000), dictionary file ru.dic & language file ru.lm

Comment: You need to use the latest model cmusphinx-ru-5.2, zero is not supported.